# How to attach GCP secret to Kubernetes service account?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

How can i use a secret object created from Google cloud JSON file into a service account? I have `minikf` on the VM and `kubeflow` installed. I am trying to make a container using `Jupyter` notebook in `minikf` Kubernetes cluster. The notebook has access to GCP using PodDefault but the kanico container started from `notebook` automatically can't access GCP.
The code in jupyter notebook for building the container is as follows:

```
IMAGE_NAME="mnist_training_kf_pipeline"
TAG="latest" # "v_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)"

GCR_IMAGE="gcr.io/{PROJECT_ID}/{IMAGE_NAME}:{TAG}".format(
    PROJECT_ID=PROJECT_ID,
    IMAGE_NAME=IMAGE_NAME,
    TAG=TAG
)

builder = kfp.containers._container_builder.ContainerBuilder(
    gcs_staging=GCS_BUCKET + "/kfp_container_build_staging")

image_name = kfp.containers.build_image_from_working_dir(
    image_name=GCR_IMAGE,
    working_dir='./tmp/components/mnist_training/',
    builder=builder
)
```

I get the error:

```
Error: error resolving source context: dialing: google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
Usage:
  executor [flags]
```

The pod name starting with Kaniko gets created and fails because it can't access the google cloud storage:
[image]

The proof of Jupyter notebook is able to utilize my secret object "user-gcp-sa" is that the above code is preparing files on GCS:
[image]

Comment: Do you run minikf VM in GCE ? Can you provide a little more details and steps you took ? Your description is unclear in a few places. You could also post some yaml files (if you have any).

Comment: I am running minikf VM in my laptop and not in GCE.

Comment: Did you manage to solve that issue?